Conditional format, highlight cell if it does NOT contain a word from a list. Cell can contain one or more words
I am trying to conditional format cells if they conatain a word NOT in a list.
I can get it to work if it is a single word but not if it is in a string.
I have tried

=NOT(ISNUMBER(--CONCAT(IFERROR(SEARCH(" "&$A$3:$A$5&" "," "&C3&" "),""))))
=SUM(--(TEXTSPLIT($C3:$C7," ")=A$3:A$5))=0
=ISNA(LOOKUP(9^9,SEARCH($A$3:$A$5,C3)))

All three work with one word in the cell but not if there are multiple.

Conditional Format Cell C2:C6 if it contains a word not in the list A2:A4

Here is an alternative option one could try :


• Formula can be used in Conditional Formatting:
=OR(ISNA(XMATCH(TEXTSPLIT(C2," "),Master_List)))


Or,
=TEXTSPLIT(C2,Master_List," ",1)<>""



Thanks Mayukh, when I paste the above into conditional formatting and choose a format colour nothing happens? both methods. Any suggestions?

Post Excel Link, to show it is not working. Clearly working on my end, without any issues.

Thanks again Mayukh, I got it working. i had not set the list name correctly. But some of the names have multiple spaces could be 1 - 8 spaces inbetween names, is there a way to set the delimiter to one or more spaces. I read you can use curled brackes { } in text split to set multiple delimiters but that wont work in conditional formating.

Again, I would like to see all those updates in the OP, not in the comments. I think you have got ample of time, to post what you have. Every second day you come up with something or the other. If you have real cause then please post proper description in the OP, or if you like can post your excel link, will take a look!

@sbarwald the update is you need to include the ignore empty param here is the updated formula: =OR(ISNA(XMATCH(TEXTSPLIT(C2," ",,1),Master_List)))

@sbarwald sounds good, please esnure to accept the answer by ticking the check mark beside it. So it helps someone in the future to follow the answer to get their query resolved!
